# Implement a user-defined malloc() function?

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, malloc

How do you create a new `malloc()` function defined in C language ?

I don't even have an elflike hint as to how to do this ,  how to map virtual space address with physical space , what algorithm to follow ? I do know that malloc() is not so efficient as it can cause fragmentation. So something efficient can be created. Even if not efficient , how to implement a naive C malloc function?

It was asked recently in an interview.

Comment: You would need OS-specic APIs. Besides I wonder why malloc would be inefficient..

Comment: There's a fairly decent implementation somewhere near the end of K&R.

Comment: i think it's inefficient for small allocations

Comment: @Thrustmaster Because it can lead to fragmentation. Efficient or Non efficient is not the problem. No OS-specific API was mentioned as such. Basic thing required was that I was required to allocate memory , but not use built-in malloc / calloc / etc. functions.

Comment: @Thrustmaster: There are a number of areas where the default implementation of malloc is less efficient than a custom implementation for many platforms.  For example, for heavily concurrent applications, an implementation that attempts to avoid false sharing can improve performance noticeably. Implementations that are optimized for the target platform can also be much more efficient than generalized implementations (e.g. embedded devices vs. high-memory servers).

Comment: Thanks a lot EricJ. and sTEAK. I now have something for the weekend ;)

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Added an answer with a summary of a very relevant Wikipedia entry.  It outlines the different kinds of things that malloc implementations try to optimize for.  That Wikipedia article is a great jumping off point for a deep dive in the world of malloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a nice example of malloc in [An example in Chapter 8.7 of C Programming Language book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628):

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia actually provides a good summary of various malloc implementations, including ones optimized for specific conditions, along with links to learn more about the implementation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

[dlmalloc](ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/)

> A general-purpose allocator. The GNU C library (glibc) uses an allocator based on dlmalloc.

[jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/)

> In order to avoid lock contention, jemalloc uses separate "arenas" for each CPU. Experiments measuring number of allocations per second in multithreading application have shown that this makes it scale linearly with the number of threads, while for both phkmalloc and dlmalloc performance was inversely proportional to the number of threads.

[Hoard memory allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoard_memory_allocator)

> Hoard uses mmap exclusively, but manages memory in chunks of 64 kilobytes called superblocks. Hoard's heap is logically divided into a single global heap and a number of per-processor heaps. In addition, there is a thread-local cache that can hold a limited number of superblocks. By allocating only from superblocks on the local per-thread or per-processor heap, and moving mostly-empty superblocks to the global heap so they can be reused by other processors, Hoard keeps fragmentation low while achieving near linear scalability with the number of threads.

[tcmalloc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#cite_note-14)

> Every thread has local storage for small allocations. For large allocations mmap or sbrk can be used. TCMalloc, a malloc developed by Google, has garbage-collection for local storage of dead threads. The TCMalloc is considered to be more than twice as fast as glibc's ptmalloc for multithreaded programs.

[dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/)  (*not covered by Wikipedia*)

> The debug memory allocation or dmalloc library has been designed as a drop in replacement for the system's malloc, realloc, calloc, free and other memory management routines while providing powerful debugging facilities configurable at runtime. These facilities include such things as memory-leak tracking, fence-post write detection, file/line number reporting, and general logging of statistics.

Comment: It's pretty surprising how selecting a malloc implementation tailored to your specific application's memory allocation needs can impact performance.  Also, using something like *dmalloc* while developing / testing is essential to finding memory management errors before they turn into insidious bugs.